# Preload pictures from JSON list and then fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I get a Json dict from a server which contains data about a image gallery like this:

```
[
    {"title": "Some Cat", "url": "http://example.com/image.png"},
    {"title": "My Foot", "url": "http://example.com/image.png"},
    {"title": "Joysticks", "url": "http://example.com/image.png"},
    ...
]
```

And i have this html snippet:

```
<div id="image-slideshow">
    <img src=""/>
</div>
```

I want that after 10 seconds, the image will be replaced with the next one of the Json dict with a "blur over" animation using jQuery.

The problem is, the picture should switch after the browser have completely loaded it to avoid an empty image. How is this possible?

Comment: You might save time by looking at [libraries that do this for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=slideshow+jquery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) considering you haven't really done anything with jquery yet with this problem.

Comment: Thanks. But i don't want 120 `<img>`-Tags in my document. I want only one (or two ...) which will be replaced